# How to change action bar size

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to change the action bar size. I have tried the following coding.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <!--  <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_style</item> -->
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/header_bar</item>
</style>
```

But the action bar size didn't change. Is there another way? I am using api level 11.

Thanks.

Comment: `android:actionBarSize` is working for me, but API level 21

Comment: best explained here http://code2care.org/pages/change-height-of-android-actionbar/

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use `height` attribute, `actionBarSize` if for something else.

```
<item name="android:height">@dimen/bar_height</item>
```

**Explanantion:**

From source code of ActionBar:

```
mContentHeight = a.getLayoutDimension(R.styleable.ActionBar_height, 0);
```

We can see that `R.styleable.ActionBar_height` is being used for height. `Stylable` property names are generated as `component_attribute` (If you have ever used a custom `stylable` view, you'd have notice this). Hence, `Actionbar` is the name of component and `height` is the name of the attribute to use. Since this is a system attribute, hence defined under `android` namespace.

**Update Dec-2014:**

[AppCompat library](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) is now provided to extend support for latest ActionBar (or Toolbar) and theme support to old android versions. Below is an example of such an application theme `/res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <!-- Main theme colors -->
        <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>

        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>

        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <!--   native widgets will now be "tinted" with accent color -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

        <!--Action bar style-->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText</item>
        <item name="android:height">@dimen/bar_height</item>
        <item name="height">@dimen/bar_height</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/bar_text_size</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/bar_text_color</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This style can now be set as app theme by using `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` in `<application>` tag of the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

**Note the use of duplicate entries**

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">
<item name="actionBarStyle">
```

The ones without `android` namespace are there for supporting both compatibility library and native attributes.Some of these attributes didn't exist under android namespace on older versions and belong to support library.

In some other places, you'll need to use `app` namespace (`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`), for example `app:showAsAction="always"` in menu xml files.

**Update Apr 2015**

[AppCompat Library v22](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20blogspot/hsDu%20(Android%20Developers%20Blog)) is also available. Read through the article to know what's new.

Comment: @user1156041   can you please elaborate me this LOC:                     mContentHeight = a.getLayoutDimension(R.styleable.ActionBar_height, 0);   what is mcontentHeight  , a etc i am newbie facing difficulty to use this

Comment: I did the above, but still the height of action bar is still fixed.

Comment: @S.D.  It does not work on Android 2.3 ... any suggestion to make it work on Android 2.3 ???

Comment: @akkilis on 2.3, You must be using Appcompat library. See updated answer.

Comment: Great answer, though I don't understand why for instance TitleText inherits from both ActionBar and AppTheme. Does it really need an actionBarStyle? Or a height set to bar_height?

Comment: On a 5.0 device I was having trouble getting this advice to work.  I found that removing the namespace from the height <item name="height">@dimen/bar_height</item> fixed it.

Answer (score 20):

Simply put `actionBarSize` item under MyTheme style, like this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">15dp</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">15dp</item>
    ...
</style>
```

**Explanation:**

In [R.styleable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#Theme_actionBarSize) we see that `R.styleable.Theme_actionBarSize` is a styleable attribute defined at Theme level.

Also, from source code [res/values/styles.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) we see how `actionBarSize` is used to set `height`:

```
<style name="Widget.ActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:height">?android:attr/actionBarSize</item>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the custom theme style XML that you are referencing from your manifest file:

```
<item name="android:windowTitleSize">58dip</item>
```

For instance if your manifest file looks something like this:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        **android:theme="@style/AppTheme"** >
```

Your theme style should be -at least- like this:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">            
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">54dip</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

S.D.'s solution does not work for me.
I used **AppCompat v-21** library in my case.
And I just add

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/actionBarSize"
android:minHeight="@dimen/actionBarSize"
```

to my layout file and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add S.D.'s code to styles.xml and then add

```
android:theme="@style/thin_ab"
```

to the `<application>` element in the main manifest.  (I'm a noob and it took me about 2 hours to find that out.)