# Changing the Size of action Bar

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-actionbar, android-titlebar

Please have a look at the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/xxx_title"
         android:layout_width="310dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/xxx_title"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
         android:textColor="#579bef"
         android:textSize="50sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Home.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Home extends Activity {

    private TextView textView23;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        //Setting up the Action Bar
         ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();  //to support lower version too
         actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); // Remove icon
         actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // Remove title text
         actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
         View customView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.window_title, null);
         actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
         actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));



        textView23 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView23);
        textView23.setSelected(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is the layout of my Action Bar. I need the height of my action bar to match to the content height of the layout, so I tried adding `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to the layout. But, it didn't change anything.

How can I change the size of the Action bar?

Comment: Do you want to change the size at runtime or in your xml? Did you try with android:layout_height="30dp" on your LinearLayout?

Comment: @JaAd: XML or code, no issue

Comment: On your xml you can change android:layout_height="wrap_content" to android:layout_height="30dp"; if it is not working, it means that you are doing something on your code at runtime.

Comment: @JaAd: it is not working

Comment: sorry, but you have to add your code when you load your custom ActionBar.

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is what i found in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439683/how-to-change-action-bar-size). You have to create a **style** for your ActionBar and then add it on code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="thin_ab" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle" >@style/thin_ab_style</item>
    </style>

    <style name="thin_ab_style" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:height">30dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then in your code add this:

```
mContentHeight = a.getLayoutDimension(R.styleable.ActionBar_height, 0);
```

BTW, if this resolve your problem, your question is a possible duplicate