# how to change height of ActionBar using Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

i am newbie i know this is a duplicate question but i am facing difficulty to set height of actionbar have used this code in res/values/style

```
<style name="thin_ab_style" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:height">70dp</item>
    </style>
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml File:

```
<activity  android:name="com.survey.management.activity.TabActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@style/thin_ab_style"/>
```

but its not changing height of actionBar.

Comment: check this one 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439683/how-to-change-action-bar-size

Comment: can you please guide me what does this LOC mean ?mContentHeight = a.getLayoutDimension(R.styleable.ActionBar_height, 0);