# Actionbar support v7 background not transparent

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have problem:
1st: I want to custom height of actionbar but it not working.

This is content in my theme.

```
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="actionBarSize">46dp</item>
        <item name="android:height">46dp</item>
        <item name="height">46dp</item>
  </style>
```

2nd. If can't change height of actionbar please tell me: "How to make background of actionbar transparent.". (I will create custom view of actionbar with Root Layout height 48dp. Then create sub view with heigh = 46dp :) ).

Please help me.
Thanks so much.

Comment: use this line in your actionbarstyle..... <item name="android:colorBackground">#00000000</item>

Comment: <style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">#00000000</item>
    </style>

I added. But it not working. :(

Comment: @Prag's It still have a black line in bottom actionbar. (I run on android v4.3)

Comment: @speedDeveloper I want to set actionbar height.(not get actionbar height)

Comment: See this to set the ActionBar height:
[Set ActionBar height][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439683/how-to-change-action-bar-size

Comment: It's not actionbar support v7. :(
I've try use actionbar sherlock. It's work for me. But actionbar support v7 - Make me headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you set `windowActionBarOverlay` to `false`.

To have your content below the action bar  :

Add this in  your style.xml from the values folder :

```
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

And this in your style.xml from the values-v14 folder :

```
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Then in your layouts, you can get the size of the action bar with this :

```
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

You need to use the attribute instead of "48dp" or "46dp" because the height changes according to different configuration (portrait/landscape, tablet/phone, ...).

To make the action bar transparent, you need to change the background. Either in your theme or by code.

```
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00000000")));
```

EDIt : I've just checked in one of my project. Apparently, setting a margin on the root of a layout for an activity doesn't work. So I did something like that :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<View //invisible view, to prevent warning
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:visibility="gone" >
</View>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

         //real content

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you. You mean I can't change height of actionbar. My application only working on portrait. So how I can't change height of actionbar support v7. (Does it can't change ?)

Comment: Thanks you. I think I will change to use Actionbar Sherlock.

Comment: It will also work with ABS, the only difference is to use `getSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: Not a terribly large difference per se but instead of `Color.parseColor("#00000000")` I'd vote for `Color.TRANSPARENT`. Simpler and self-documenting.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000")));
```