# How To Reduce Height of Action Bar in Android Layout

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

After trying so many codes, I failed to find perfect answer. Here I come to ask you guys how to change height of action bar in specific layout. I'm using Appcompat theme and my coding is,

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FF4081</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the new theme and use this:
[How to change action bar size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439683/how-to-change-action-bar-size)

Or use the Android Developers site: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.LayoutParams.html