# Android Studio - layout_height + x pixels

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Sorry guys. I am new ish to using android studio. I was wondering if it is possible to set the layout height of the toolbar to

> ?attr/actionBarSize
>   + 15px

Thanks in advance

> android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize+15px"

Does not work for me. Thanks again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android)

Comment: possible duplicate [How to change action bar size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439683/how-to-change-action-bar-size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is not possible to setup in XML like that. For that you need to do it in Java.

For that you do the method shown on the following question to get the `actionBarSize` valued https://stackoverflow.com/a/13216807/906362

and then set it to the view you want with:

```
view.getLayoutParams().height = actionBarHeight + 15;
```